# Create friendly URLs like this for XenForo 2?

Tags: url, vbulletin, xenforo

Does anyone know how to create URLs like this for Xenforo 2?

https://forumweb.hosting/95-web-hosting/

https://forumweb.hosting/13199-putty-vs-bitvise-tunnelier.html

I have setup a new Xenforo 2 but I can not change URL structure like the site above, I want to setup this because I am having a vBulletin 4 forum that using DBtech SEO URL, it has same structure with forumweb.

I am not sure which should I change on Xenforo 2 to make my URLs (XF2) like this, If I can do this, I don't need to use redirects function of Xenforo when moving my vB forum to Xf forum platform.

Please guide me.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

DBtech does have a Xenforo 2 redirect addon but it is unsupported, you could try it on a test forum and see if it fulfills your needs:
https://xenforo.com/community/resources/dbtech-dragonbyte-seo-urls-to-xenforo-2.6361/

If it doesn't fit your needs exactly maybe you can modify it if you got the skills.

The regular Xenforo Friendly URLS look like this, just FYI:

http://www.example.com/threads/thread-title-here.12345/

http://www.example.com/exampleforum.6789/

The regular Xenforo VB4 redirect addon works perfectly for a regular vBulletin board:
https://xenforo.com/community/resources/xenforo-redirects-for-vbulletin.6123/updates

I just upgraded from VB4 to Xenforo2 and I could not be happier!

Comment: Thanks GuidedHacking for your answer but this is using redirections for URLs, not rewrite URLs as my expection.
I sent a PM to Mike (Xenforo deveoper) and he told me that that needs a custom mod.